# cannot create from a factoryBoy class

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I try to make a class a make some instances but I can't create any instance with the class in my django shell

factories.py

```
import factory
from webshare.models import WebShareFileFolders


class WebShareFileFactoryBoy(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = WebShareFileFolders

    inode = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    name = factory.Faker('name')
    path = factory.Faker('text', max_nb_chars=50)
    is_dir = factory.Faker('boolean')
```

and then the error in my console

```
>>> from webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy

>>> instance = WebShareFileFactoryBoy()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

>>> instance = WebShareFileFactoryBoy.create()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'webshare.tests.factories.WebShareFileFactoryBoy' has no attribute 'create'
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Python 3.7.9
factory-boy 3.3.0

I just try to make instance from a factory class

edit :
the solution is the import method

`from webshare.tests.factories.WebShareFileFactoryBoy import WebShareFileFactoryBoy`
factories is the directory and the python file have the same name than the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake when I import the class

the problem:
`from webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy`

the solution:
`from webshare.tests.factories.WebShareFileFactoryBoy import WebShareFileFactoryBoy`

factories is the directory and the python file have the same name than the class

second solution:
in the **init**.py add

`from .WebShareFileFactoryBoy import WebShareFileFactoryBoy`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
import factory
from ...webshare.models import WebShareFileFolders


class WebShareFileFactoryBoy(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = WebShareFileFolders

    inode = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    name = factory.Faker('name')
    path = factory.Faker('text', max_nb_chars=50)
    is_dir = factory.Faker('boolean')
```

Comment: ```
>>>from webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webshare.webshare'
```

Comment: Did you use my code?

Comment: See `from ...webshare.models ` it's different from your code. Dots.

Comment: these is a screenshoot from the directory
https://snipboard.io/c9j2Dk.jpg

Comment: yes of course I use it, save, quit the django console and re-import the new class

Comment: the line "from ...webshare.models import WebShareFileFolders" is in the python file, but in the django console I write 
>>> from webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy

Comment: Yes............

Comment: did I misunderstand?

Comment: In console, use relative path relative to manage.py file.

Comment: `from tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy` or `from webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy`.

Comment: "webshare.tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy" was initialy that was I use and raise : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webshare.webshare'

and the first options that you propose raise :
>>> from tests.factories import WebShareFileFactoryBoy
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'

Comment: from webshare.tests.factories.WebShareFileFactoryBoy import WebShareFileFactoryBoy
was the solution, factories is the directory and the python file have the same name than the class

Comment: So second option works. It was this hard to give the frist time, because you didn't mention you executing it from console. That's why dots are not required. Always remember to use relative paths. Worked path is the relative path from console.

Comment: sorry for missing that, and thank you for your help ;)